# How to send the contents of a file downloaded from aws s3 using apache camel in json format?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-camel

I have a rest api using apache camel. When I hit a post request on a route, it gets a file from S3. Here is the code for that ->

```
public static class HelloRoute extends RouteBuilder {
       
        @Override
        public void configure() {
            rest("/")
                .post("file-from-s3")
                    .route()
                    .setHeader(AWS2S3Constants.KEY, constant("filename"))
                    .to("aws2-s3://bucketname?accessKey=INSERT&secretKey=INSERT&region=INSERT&operation=getObject")
                    .endRest();
          }
}
```

This gives the content of the file in Postman. I want the response in a json format where the contents of the file will be in the `content` key of json. How to do this?

Comment: Create a pojo matching the format of your json and map your file to the pojo using a json library such as jackson or gson. You can then manipulate the pojo as you wish.

Comment: @SneharghyaPathak I am doing that only but the issue is that my body is of type ```software.amazon.awssdk.core.ResponseInputStream``` when executing the ```to``` statement. How do I convert it into a String??

Comment: did you try a convertBodyTo(String.class)

Comment: ```.process(new org.apache.camel.Processor(){
                        @Override
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                            String data = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                            Response response = new Response();
                            response.setContent(data);
                            exchange.getIn().setBody(response);
                        }```  I wrote this processor, with Response as pojo. But the setBody is not giving the output of the file.

Comment: @SneharghyaPathak can you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62763173/how-to-do-custom-error-handling-in-an-apache-camel-rest-api

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have binding mode enabled (auto|json) in your REST configuration and the consumes/produces set on your route. Now write your processor to build your response object and set it in the body. Camel will handle the rest for you.

```
public static class HelloRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    restConfiguration().component("netty-http").host("localhost").port(portNum).bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);
   
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        rest("/")
            .post("file-from-s3")
                .consumes("application/json").type(YourRequest.class)
                .produces("application/json").outType(YourResponse.class)
                .route()
                .setHeader(AWS2S3Constants.KEY, constant("filename"))
                .to("aws2-s3://bucketname?accessKey=INSERT&secretKey=INSERT&region=INSERT&operation=getObject")
                //.process("responseBuilderProcessor")
                .endRest();
      }
```

}