# How to do custom error handling in an apache camel rest api?

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, apache-camel

I have an apache camel rest api which downloads a file from S3. I send json input`(key, bucketname, accessKey, secretKey, region)` in order to write the URI. The code looks like this:

```
public static class HelloRoute extends RouteBuilder {
       
   @Override
   public void configure() {
     rest("/")
     .post("file-from-s3")
     .route()
     .setHeader(AWS2S3Constants.KEY, key)
     .to("aws2-s3://bucketname?accessKey=INSERT&secretKey=INSERT&region=INSERT&operation=getObject")
      .endRest();
          }
}
```

I am able to get the respective json input in the places mentioned in the above code by using a `JSONObject` as the body.

If suppose, I enter a wrong value in my json input(for ex accessKey), I get an error like

```
The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID: 6923BEC55C1FD5F1, Extended Request ID: re5Rb7I76j9jvGqhSQXgjUoMwOZqsprg22bOGD+BDbuj0zrRrf0FceLaapvpR4KcNDY6GntNiF0=)
```

which is not very user friendly. How can I write a custom error handler for this which will just return an error message for the above case like  `Wrong Access Key`

Comment: Can you post full stacktrace to see, if the exception is directly `AmazonS3Exception` or is wrapped within another exception?

Comment: @Bedla I am getting this error ```org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: aws2-s3://accesskey=AKIARGSIOJPSQRMGNS5&secretkey=xxxxxx&bucketname=jcnu-2020-swarnim-shukla&region=us-east-1&operation=getObject due to: useIAMCredentials is set to false, AmazonS3Client or accessKey and secretKey must be specified```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use "onException" clause and create your own response in a processor there. See: https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/exception-clause.html

```java
onException(TheThrownException.class)
    .handled(...) //--> depend on your need true or false
    .continued(...) //--> depend on your need true or false
    .process("processor1")
    .to("direct:error-handling-endpoint")
```